# How to upgrade several packages to specific version?

Tags: yarnpkg

I use yarn
I have an @angular application with lib modules in several repos.
I want to upgrade all @angular dependencies from one module to the version from another one. NOT to the latest Bugfix

desired version: 11.2.7
latest: 11.2.13

How can I do that?

with

```
yarn upgrade --scope @angular
```

they get upgraded to 11.2.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn add package-name` this will install the "latest" version of the package.

`yarn add package-name@1.2.3` this will install a specific version of a package from the registry.

`yarn add package-name@tag` this will install a specific "tag" (e.g. beta, next, or latest).

You should use `yarn add angular@11.2.7`

Comment: I think this would only apply to a package called angular. I want to upgrade all my angular scoped packages at once. @angular/core, @angular/compiler, @angular/...

Answer (score 0):

you can install a specific version of a dependency with yarn using the following command:
`yarn add dependency@version`

so in your case you would use:
`yarn add angular@11.2.7`

[Reference](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add/)

Comment: I think this would only apply to a package called angular. I want to upgrade all my angular scoped packages at once. @angular/core, @angular/compiler, @angular/...